# How to suppress page footer section when report footer section show?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

My report will have list of user's name and space for their signature at the end of report. How can I hide footer page when report footer show. Report footer may continue multiple pages.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppress your page footer if the last record has been printed. Add a conditonal supression to your page footer containing `OnLastRecord`.